# Optimizing a T-SQL query featuring While loop and Cross Apply

Tags: loops, t-sql, query-optimization, cross-apply

Seeking to optimize a T-SQL query written to calculate a rolling 12M Revenue amount. The major issue is I need calculate it across 6 dimensions, resulting in 45,000+ combinations that each need their own rolling revenue. Each combination is taking about 5 minutes to calculate. Due to the nature of the business, the combinations will grow over time.

All actions need to be completed as a sub-query.

```
DECLARE @NUMBER INT
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT = 0
DECLARE @REFERENCE VARCHAR(50)

SET @NUMBER =
    (SELECT MAX(r.Row)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                a.GroupKey
                ,a.LevelKey
                ,a.StateKey
                ,a.ProductKey
                ,a.OptionKey
                ,a.LocKey
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.GroupKey ASC) AS Row
            FROM Members AS a
            GROUP BY 
                a.GroupKey
                ,a.LevelKey
                ,a.StateKey
                ,a.ProductKey
                ,a.OptionKey
                ,a.LocKey ) r)
BEGIN
DECLARE @OUTPUT TABLE (
        RefKey VARCHAR(50)
        ,DateID INT
        ,GroupKey INT
        ,LevelKey INT
        ,StateKey INT
        ,ProductKey INT
        ,OptionKey INT
        ,LocKey INT
        ,Revenue DECIMAL(28,9)
        ,Rolling12Months DECIMAL(28,9)
         )

WHILE @ROWCOUNT < @NUMBER

BEGIN
SET @REFERENCE =
    (SELECT r.RefKey
        FROM (
            SELECT
                r.Refkey
                ,r.Row
                FROM (          
                    SELECT 
                        CONCAT( a.GroupKey, '-',a.LevelKey, '-',a.StateKey, '-',a.ProductKey, '-',a.OptionKey, '-',a.LocKey) AS RefKey
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.GroupKey ASC) AS Row
                    FROM Members AS a
                    GROUP BY 
                        a.GroupKey
                        ,a.LevelKey
                        ,a.StateKey
                        ,a.ProductKey
                        ,a.OptionKey
                        ,a.LocKey ) r) r WHERE r.Row = @ROWCOUNT + 1 )

INSERT INTO @OUTPUT         
SELECT
    a.RefKey
    ,a.DateID
    ,a.GroupKey
    ,a.LevelKey
    ,a.StateKey
    ,a.ProductKey
    ,a.OptionKey
    ,a.LocKey
    ,a.Revenue
    ,Rolling12Months=a.Revenue + b.RM 

FROM (

        SELECT
            CONVERT(datetime,STR(CI.DateID)) AS Date
            ,CI.DateID
            ,CI.GroupKey
            ,CI.LevelKey
            ,CI.StateKey
            ,CI.ProductKey
            ,CI.OptionKey
            ,CI.LocKey
            ,CONCAT( CI.GroupKey, '-',CI.LevelKey, '-',CI.StateKey, '-',CI.ProductKey, '-',CI.OptionKey, '-',CI.LocKey) AS RefKey
            ,SUM(CI.Revenue) AS Revenue
        FROM Members AS CI
        WHERE CONCAT( CI.GroupKey, '-',CI.LevelKey, '-',CI.StateKey, '-',CI.ProductKey, '-',CI.OptionKey, '-',CI.LocKey) = @REFERENCE
        GROUP BY CI.DateID,CI.StateKey,CI.GroupKey  ,CI.LevelKey,CI.StateKey,CI.ProductKey,CI.OptionKey ,CI.LocKey

        ) a
CROSS APPLY
( 
    SELECT RM=SUM(b.Revenue)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 11 b.Date, b.Revenue 
        FROM (

                SELECT
                    CONVERT(datetime,STR(CI.DateID)) AS Date
                    ,CI.DateID
                    ,CI.GroupKey
                    ,CI.LevelKey
                    ,CI.StateKey
                    ,CI.ProductKey
                    ,CI.OptionKey
                    ,CI.LocKey
                    ,CONCAT( CI.GroupKey, '-',CI.LevelKey, '-',CI.StateKey, '-',CI.ProductKey, '-',CI.OptionKey, '-',CI.LocKey) AS RefKey
                    ,SUM(CI.Revenue) AS Revenue
                FROM Members AS CI
                WHERE CONCAT( CI.GroupKey, '-',CI.LevelKey, '-',CI.StateKey, '-',CI.ProductKey, '-',CI.OptionKey, '-',CI.LocKey) = @REFERENCE
                GROUP BY CI.DateID,CI.StateKey,CI.GroupKey  ,CI.LevelKey,CI.StateKey,CI.ProductKey,CI.OptionKey ,CI.LocKey

        ) b
        WHERE b.Date < a.Date AND b.RefKey = a.RefKey
        ORDER BY b.Date DESC
    ) b
) b

    SET @ROWCOUNT = @ROWCOUNT + 1
    END
    SELECT * FROM @OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is probably to get rid of the loop. SQL don't play well with loops, you should find a set based approach to replace that, if possible. I didn't read the code you've posted but it's kind of a golden rule in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Zohar. I'm unsure of any approach that doesn't use a loop in order to cluster the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of point with your code

Try using a temp table intead of a table variable - a table variable might have performance issue with many rows.

It looks nice an concise to generate a key on the fly, by concatenating a lot of columns, but you kill the use of any indexes or statistics when you do that. Join on the seperate columns if you need to, in stead of using a function on them.

You convert your date column to a datetime, and then join on it - again you should just used the unchanged column for comparison.

You have not explained about your date column - you calculate your rolling 12 months simply as the top 11 last dates less than current date, plus current date

```
,Rolling12Months=a.Revenue + b.RM
```

and

```
 SELECT RM=SUM(b.Revenue)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 11 b.Date, b.Revenue
```

Have you considered that there might be more than one date pr month? int that case you would get less than 12 months of data in you sum. Or ii, for some combination of your group by columns, there are months without data, in that case your sum would be for more months!

However if we just need to sum the last 12 dates for each combination of the group by columns, then I would just do it like this:

```
/* When using many rows a temp table often performs better than a table variable */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OUTPUT

CREATE TABLE #OUTPUT  (
        RefKey VARCHAR(50)
        ,DateID INT
        ,GroupKey INT
        ,LevelKey INT
        ,StateKey INT
        ,ProductKey INT
        ,OptionKey INT
        ,LocKey INT
        ,Revenue DECIMAL(28,9)
        ,Rolling12Months DECIMAL(28,9)
         )

/* I am doing a simple select and using the analytical sum, which can be set up with a window */
SELECT
    CONCAT(CI.GroupKey, '-', CI.LevelKey, '-', CI.StateKey, '-', CI.ProductKey, '-', CI.OptionKey, '-', CI.LocKey) RefKey
   ,CI.DateID
   ,CI.GroupKey
   ,CI.LevelKey
   ,CI.StateKey
   ,CI.ProductKey
   ,CI.OptionKey
   ,CI.LocKey
   ,CI.Revenue
   ,SUM(CI.Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY CI.GroupKey, CI.LevelKey, CI.StateKey
    , CI.ProductKey, CI.OptionKey, CI.LocKey ORDER BY CI.DateID 
    ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) Rolling12Months
FROM Members AS CI
GROUP BY
    CI.DateID
   ,CI.GroupKey
   ,CI.LevelKey
   ,CI.StateKey
   ,CI.ProductKey
   ,CI.OptionKey
   ,CI.LocKey

SELECT
    *
FROM #OUTPUT
```

This ought to give you the same result, however I would not use it as it stands, since it just returns the sum of the last 11 dates plus current date for each combination of columns! But if it works in your original code, this should replicate your results